# How to make discord close a ticket channel?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    #new_channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"ticket-{message.author.name}")
    name = 'TICKETS'
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    foundchan = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"Ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
    if category is None:
        await ctx.guild.create_category(name)

    if foundchan is None:
        channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ctx.author.name}', category=category)
    if foundchan:
        await ctx.channel.send("ALREADY A  CHANNEL")
    Role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Ticket Support")
    if Role is None:
        await ctx.guild.create_role(name="Ticket Support")
    else:
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, view_channel=True)
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, view_channel=False)
        await channel.set_permissions(Role, view_channel=True, send_messages=True, add_reactions=True)
        await channel.send(f"Hey, {ctx.author.mention}, thank you for creating a ticket; please be patient untill one of our staff member to come.")
        await channel.send("**Say '*close' to close the ticket.**")


@client.command()
async def close(ctx):
    foundchan = discord.utils.get(
        ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
    # await discord.Member.send(f"Your ticket was closed by {ctx.author.name}")
    await foundchan.delete()
#Here is the full code everything is working but when i try to delete the channel it doesnt work and give me this error  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

I need help it gives me this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'

a help would be really appreciated cause its been so long and i cant find out the solution, tysm for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the correct channel name, when creating you are using this.

```py
channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ctx.author.name}', category=category)
```

You used `Ticket` with a capital `T` but when getting the channel you used `ticket`.

```py
foundchan = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.text_channels, name=f"ticket-{ctx.author.name}")
```

Also another advice use `author.id` since It can't be changed unlike the name

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: I have not used `id` in my code so at what exactly are you referring ? if you mean author then it should be `ctx.author.id` and make sure it is a Member object print the type of it.

Comment: No bro like when someone says *ticket it creates  ticket and adds the member who made the ticket with Ticket Support role into channel perms so i want when i say *close to delete the ticket channel

Comment: IT WORKS OMG YAY YES I USE AUTHOR ID NOW THANK YOU SO MUCH BRO <3